# Best Sensor(s) to Detect Distance to Person Within Range of At Least Several Feet, 360 Degrees

Tags: sensor, distance

I am new to electrical engineering, with most of my experience being in programming, so this is an exploratory question in order to determine how feasible it is to do what I want to do.

I am looking to find the cheapest/simplest way to have a sensor or array of sensors vary their output based on the distance to a nearby person, with the following criteria:

- Range of ideally around 15 feet, but at least 5-10
- Able to sense in 360 degrees, or close to it (may require multiple sensors)
- Will not output distance to nearby stationary non-human objects (either using IR or some sort of filtering?)
- Low precision is fine, output does not need to be particularly granular or accurate
- Output should update no slower than every five seconds

I was looking into PIR sensors, but it seems like they are set up to output a boolean representing whether motion was detected. Ultrasonic sensors seem promising, but it seems like I would require several of them for full coverage, and I'm not sure what the best way to ignore non-human objects would be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the sensor at a fixed position in a fixed environment (I.e. the only “things” that move relative to the sensor are humans), or does either the sensor move or the environment change? Do you have power constraints (e.g. running on battery)? Is there only one person or several? Do you need to detect stationary people or only those who move?

Answer (score 2):

Detecting people and telling them from walls, trashcans, gas stations, bikes, or vegetable shelves is **Hard** with a capital H. I think your best bet is probably a camera (visible light or infrared, or both), combined with controlled illumination, machine learning and maybe an additional laser scanner or array of ultrasonic distance sensors to verify the distance of a detected person. Uff.

Comment: Modern IP cameras have a human detection. It recognize human body by shape.

Comment: exactly, using a camera + machine learning. The only thing missing then is a good distance sensor.

Answer (score 2):

If the area in which you want to detect humans is relatively clear of any other objects or the clutter is stationary then a simple Lidar will work well.
This [unit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4010?gclid=Cj0KCQjwh_eFBhDZARIsALHjIKcVird5g-Hs22Rtuhuj28bTPAnQ367SBDZwjpoNUaIT_TGgYiqOAW8aAj8VEALw_wcB) is about $100 and gives absolutely stellar radial resolution with very little post processing overhead.

There are even smaller non-mechanical laser TOF sensors such as the [VL53L3CX](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/imaging-and-photonics-solutions/time-of-flight-sensors/vl53l3cx.html) (you'd need multiple of course) for about $10-12.
These are good for area detection, but low radial accuracy. They emit a cone shaped coverage good out to 3-5m.